# how to retrieve number from firebase in phoneauth

Tags: android

I am new here to create an app in android studio. I am using firebase phone authentication for login and I want to retrieve number that enter in EditText. How to retrieve phone number from firebase using phone authentication.

Answer (score 0):

To get user.
`FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();`

If user object is not null, he is logged in. Then use `getPhoneNumber()` on user ti get phone no

`if(user != null) String number = user.getPhoneNumber();`

If  number is null, no phone number was added.

[getPhoneNumber()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getPhoneNumber())

> Returns the phone number of the user, as stored in the Firebase project's user database, or null if none exists.

Comment: @Amankumar check this repo https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android